# Problemi col congiuntivo

Tags: grammar, verbs, subjunctive-mood

È lecito dire: "Ho la certezza che l'algoritmo funziona", oppure bisogna usare il congiuntivo "Ho la certezza che l'algoritmo funzioni"? E se occorre il congiuntivo, come si giustifica?

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @RobertoTognelli!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il congiuntivo è il modo del dubbio, dell'ipotesi, dell'eventualità. Se stiamo parlando di certezze, di fatti – fossero anche tali solo nell'opinione di chi parla – usiamo l'indicativo. Pensa, per analogia, alla differenza tra «Spero che l'algoritmo funzioni» e «So che l'algoritmo funziona».

Comment: Grazie, grazie mille!!

Comment: @RobertoTognelli , scherzandoci sopra, occhio che quella che hai usato come esempio pero' e' un'affermazione pesante! :)

Answer (score 0):

La risposta alla tua domanda è che entrambe le forme sono corrette. La forma col congiuntivo assegna semplicemente alla frase un tono più "alto".

La domanda ha senso, però, dal momento che la strategia usata nelle scuole italiane per spiegare il congiuntivo fa acqua da tutte le parti. Io parlerei senza mezzi termini di "fantagrammatica". Se la grammatica deve spiegare come funziona la lingua, la storiella del congiuntivo come "modo dell'ipotesi, del timore, della paura e bla, bla, bla" semplicemente non regge. È facilissimo costruire frasi dove il congiuntivo non ci starebbe (in accordo a quella regola), ma gli italiani avvertono che, a orecchio, "ci sta" (pur non sapendolo spiegare ovviamente).

L'uso del congiuntivo italiano è un retaggio del latino ed è legato prevalentemente alla possibilità di conferire ai propri scritti un tono più elevato qualora il registro lo richieda.

Ho scritto un articolo in proposito che dovrebbe dissipare la maggior parte dei dubbi: https://www.lavocedinewyork.com/arts/lingua-italiana/2019/10/25/il-congiuntivo-italiano-cari-studenti-stranieri-attenti-alla-fantagrammatica/